# Empty ActiveRecord::Relations do not compare in RSpec

Tags: activerecord, rspec, rspec-rails

I simplified my RSpec comparison problem down to this:

`expect(DetailObjective.all.limit(0)).to eq(DetailObjective.none)`

which returns a failed result:

`expected: #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

`got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

```
 (compared using ==)
```

which seems like they DO match? How do I compare these empty Relations? I do not want to compare something fake like be_empty as that tells nothing about the comparative structures, just content.

Answer (score 0):

`DetailObjective.all.limit(0)` and `DetailObjective.none` both return a new instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`, but `eq` returns `false` when the objects are not identical -- that is to say, they are not the same object. You can see this easily by assigning the output of each method to a local variable and checking its `object_id` -- they will be different.

> I do not want to compare something fake like be_empty ...

Not sure what you mean by 'fake'. Collections are complex types -- comparing them is not like comparing integers. Are they the same when the have the same members? When the members are in the same order? When the members are the same class?

Comparing one empty collection with another empty collection doesn't seem to make much sense ... can you be explicit about what you are trying to accomplish here?